# Bootstrap 4 modal window doesn't open

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to open a modal with Bootstrap 4. I don't see any errors in the console or in the HTML itself, but the modal doesn't show.

Here's a part of the code:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>Casper Group</td>
    <td>700eabd7-b830-4f26-a940-d5f131c68d7f</td>
    <td>2018-08-18 09:16:01</td>
    <td class="text-right">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModal-1" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal for delete confirmation -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="#confirmDeleteModal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmDeleteModalLabel-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="confirmDeleteModalLabel-1">Confirm delete</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Are you sure you want to delete the details of "Casper Group"?
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <form method="POST" action="#">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="k7hGv6Bddupv0KBOY2m8xkmro6lpfZeAgqcwT1MC">                                                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">                                                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/160726/), maybe one of you guys has an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `#` on `data-target` because that's `jQuery` selector but you don't need `#` on the modal element IDs.

Remove `#` on those 3 modals should fix it.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmDeleteModal-1" ... >
```

Comment: Thanks! Rookie mistake :)